# Table GENTABLE has no column named TABLE_AMOUNT

Tags: android

I have searched every where but not getting the solution, even i have added space after types

```
private final String CREATE_TABLE="Create Table " + TABLE_NAME +
"(" 
+ TABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
+ TABLE_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
+ TABLE_ACCT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
+ TABLE_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
+ TABLE_STS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ")"; 

public static final String DB_NAME="GENERALJOURNAL";
    public static final int DB_VERSION=16;
public static final String TABLE_NAME="GENTABLE";
public static final String TABLE_ID="_id";
public static final String TABLE_AMOUNT="amount";
public static final String TABLE_ACCT="account";
public static final String TABLE_DATE="date";
public static final String TABLE_STS="status";
```

Comment: GENTABLE has no column TABLE_AMOUNT, what is the problem to understand this? The table you need to search is amount

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think that there is a typo. Change your table creation code to

```
private final String CREATE_TABLE="Create Table " + TABLE_NAME +
"( TABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
 + TABLE_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
 + TABLE_ACCT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
 + TABLE_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
 + TABLE_STS + " TEXT NOT NULL )";
```